# ¿Por qué no puedo entrar al chat estando logueado?

Tags: soporte, bug, estado-no-reproducido

Ya hace días que llevo observando este comportamiento para los chats de los comentarios.

Sin embargo, hoy he descubierto el chat general (bueno, más bien, me han ayudado a encontrarlo jeje) y he visto que el comportamiento es el mismo.

Lo que pasa es que estando todo el rato logueado a Stackoverflow en español, hay veces que puedo postear en el chat sin problemas y otras que me pide loguearme. Intento meter mis credenciales pero me dice que son incorrectas.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

**Posdata**: Aquí tenéis una imagen que acabo de sacar mientras escribo esto y en la cual se ve que no me deja introducir valores en el chat y me pide loguearme. Sin embargo, hace un rato, he podido postear en el chat sin problemas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pongo las etiquetas de bug y de soporte ya que no sé realmente si es un bug o es que estoy haciendo algo mal.

Comment: Prueba con otro navegador a ver que pasa...  para ir descartando. (soy @ArtEze)

Comment: _"Qué sueño horrendo que tuve, soñé que podía editar comentarios de los demás"_... ¡Fue una premonición!

Comment: @EmanuelVe Mira.

Comment: @ArtEze wow.. editaste mi comentario?

Comment: @EmanuelVe Sip.

Comment: @ArtEze tengo miedo XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final creo que he conseguido solucionarlo.

Realmente, no sé cuál fue el motivo para que no me funcionara el chat aunque tiene pinta de que fue cosa de mi navegador que, aún borrando cookies, historial, caché y demás, seguía sin dejarme entrar.

Una vez hecho esto, y como vi que en Firefox si que funcionaba (yo estaba usando Google Chrome), desinstale Google Chrome y lo volví a instalar.

Y... ¡eureka!¡Ha vuelto a funcionar!

Answer (score 0):

¡Uy estoy yo ahí!

Quizás hay que borrar las cookies y entrar con Google o la forma convencional.

Yo uso una extensión del navegador Chrome llamada, EditThisCookie, y al cliquear en el tacho de basura, me borra todas las cookies del sitio actual.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/editthiscookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=es-419

Comment: La verdad que eso ya lo había probado y me pasa lo mismo. Igual mañana le da la gana de entrar ^^

Comment: @Error404 No se me ocurre nada, debe ser que tu internet está lento.

Comment: No, porque el resto de la página me funciona perfectamente. Lo único que intento loguearme cuando me sale ese mensaje con las credenciales de Stackoverflow y me sale todo el rato que son erróneas.

Comment: Intenta cuando puedas nombrarme en el chat de manera que me salga la notificación. Antes he entrado así al chat mediante otro usuario. Simplemente para probar más posibilidades.

Comment: @Error404 Listo, aunque no pasó nada.

Comment: No, a mí tampoco me apareció la notificación :( **Edit:** Si que me salio pero me sigue sin dejar poder introducir nada.